# Matlab: Can't handle data

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing a program in Matlab that reads in a Matrix coming from a sensor (microcontroller is an Arduino Leonardo). You can choose how fast the matrices are being recorded (e.g. 60 frames per min would be one matrix every second).

All that works great, but I had to create a default file that records all the matrices that would not be recorded (let’s say it’s fast enough to record 8 matrices per sec and you only want one per sec, then the default file would record the other seven). Otherwise I’d get kicked out of here:

```
%Get data
%Data is read as string (CSV)
data = str2double(strsplit(fgetl(serialPort), ','));

if and(get(hObject,'Value') == 1, correctPort == 1)
    %try for right ports
    try
        %Reshape data (1D -> 2D array) and display in matrix
        k = 1;
        for i = 1:nrow
            for j = 1:ncol
                % Reading in tag names
                tagNames{k} = ['tag_matrix_' num2str(k)];
                % Creating matrix
                data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k);
                % Display in matrix
                set(handles.(tagNames{k}),'String',data2d(i,j));
                set(handles.(tagNames{k}),'visible','on');
                k = k + 1;
            end
        end
    catch
        set(handles.tag_txt3,'String','This is not the correct port. Please look up the correct port in your Device Manager. Set up the right port and start again');
        set(handles.tag_OnOff,'Value',0);
        set(handles.tag_log,'Value',0);
        set(handles.tag_log,'Enable','off')
        correctPort = 0;
    end
end
```

It goes through the loop a couple of time (a different number of times every time) but eventually I’ll get send to “catch”. This happens if i started recording or not. Doesn't matter.

If I have it display the matrices in the Command Window (`data2d(row_index(i), col_index(j)) = data(k)` without `;`) it works.

Here is how I record the data:

```
% Open for writing
% Preparation
if and(startLog == 1, correctPort == 1)
    set(handles.tag_txt3,'String','Program running and recording data');
end
% Set interval = recTime after logging (don't worry about that)
if and(startLog == 1, counter == 0)
    interval = recTime;
    counter = 1;
end
% Making sure you have to restart after stop logging
if and(startLog == 0, counter == 1)
    set(handles.tag_OnOff,'Value',0)
end
% Record data when the time has come
if and(startLog == 1,time > interval)
    fprintf(fid, '#');
    fprintf(fid, '%u', matrixNumber);
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
    for i=1:size(data2d,1)
        fprintf(fid, '%g\t', data2d(i,:));
        fprintf(fid,'\n');
    end
    interval = recTime + interval;
    matrixNumber = matrixNumber + 1;
    %Making sure you have choosen a unit and send out error
elseif and(startLog == 1,recTime == 0)
    set(handles.tag_txt3,'String','Choose a unit and start again');
    set(handles.tag_OnOff,'Value',0)
    set(handles.tag_log,'Value',0)
    counter = 0;
else
    %This is where the default file would be recording all the other matrices
end
```

Hope someone can help me. I didn't wanna put in the entire code because it's already ten pages. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Thank you so much in advance

Mike

Comment: You are already recording the data you want to capture in a file (in your code paragraph: `% Record data when the time has come`). So what prevents you to use the same method to record these "other" matrices in a different file ?

Comment: In order to be able to record as many matrices per sec as possible i need to make sure the programm runns as fast as possible. also this is getting grated and it's hard to defend a default file because i didnt know any better

Comment: well, provided you close them properly when the time comes, nothing stops you from opening 2 files at the same time `fidmain=fopen('mainfile.txt',...);fid2=fopen('OtherMatrices.txt',...);`. Then every time a matrix is read from the port, use the same writing code, but decide on which `fid` to send it based on your own decision tree.

Comment: i did that and it works. my question is why wouldnt it work if i leave it out.

Comment: and how can i make it work without putting my trash data into another file. writing a file is time consuming and i try to make the loop as fast as possible

Comment: I am sincerely lost here ... In your question you are asking how to record extra data in a separate file ... then you ask how to make it work without using another file ??? Do you need to save these "trash" data or not ? (If you are concerned about speed of writing, I would suggest to use _binary_ everywhere you can instead of _ASCII_).

Comment: i dont wanna save the trash data. it only works if i save the trash data (or if i have any other delay in the loop). i'm trying to make it work withought recording another file. sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: the problem is in try-catch. if i put in anything that is shows in the command window (so i guess it takes up time) it works